# I am working with Django inclusion_tag and Wagtail Site Setting

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail

I am new in Django and Wagtail and I am facing little problem.

I want to assess Wagtail Site Setting using Django inclusion_tag.

in short, {{ settings.app_1.SimpleHtmlSettings.heading }} and {{ settings.app_1.SimpleHtmlSettings.body }} in index.html is not printing any thing.

I tried total two solutions but non of them is working

1. app_1_extras.py (simple_html = SimpleHtmlSettings.for_site(context['request'].site))
2. app_1_extras.py (simple_html = SimpleHtmlSettings.objects.first)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting

# Create your models here.

@register_setting
class SimpleHtmlSettings(BaseSetting):
    heading = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, help_text='Enter heading')
    body = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, help_text='Enter body content')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app_1.models import SimpleHtmlSettings
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app_1/test.html')
```

app_1_extras.py

```
from django import template
from app_1.models import SimpleHtmlSettings

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('app_1/index.html', takes_context=True)
def show_results(context):
    # simple_html = SimpleHtmlSettings.for_site(context['request'].site)
    simple_html = SimpleHtmlSettings.objects.first
    return {'simple_html': simple_html}
```

index.py

```
{% load wagtailsettings_tags %}

<h1>{{ settings.app_1.SimpleHtmlSettings.heading }}</h1>

<p>{{ settings.app_1.SimpleHtmlSettings.body }}</p>

<p>Check</p>
```

test.py

```
{% load wagtailsettings_tags %}
{% load app_1_extras %}

{% show_results %}
```

test.html only printing "Check"

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up the variable `simple_html` to be available in your `index.html` template, and then never using that variable. index.html should become:

```
<h1>{{ simple_html.heading }}</h1>

<p>{{ simple_html.body }}</p>

<p>Check</p>
```